# Template script to make it visible only to admin on shopify

Tags: javascript, php, web-applications, shopify

I would like to make a template on shopify visible only to admins. 
I can make it visible to customers only, but need a code for admin only now.

The code for customers I use is:

```
{% unless customer %}
    {% if template contains 'customer' %}
        {% assign send_to_login = false %}
    {% else %}
        {% assign send_to_login = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endunless %}

{% if send_to_login %}
<meta content="0; url=/account/login?checkout_url={{ shop.url }}" http-equiv="refresh" />
{% else %}
==== Page Content ===
{% endif %}
//The code above asks to the user to login if they visit this template
```

Now is it possible to make something similar to this for the admins only? What is the name for the admin entity? Here for example the entity customer is 'customer'. How should I declare the admin in the code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these similar questions:

- [How to check if current visitor is shop's admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470921/howto-check-if-current-visitor-is-shops-admin)
- [Check if current customer is an admin in Shopify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177919/check-if-current-customer-is-an-admin-in-shopify)
- [Check if current customer/user is an admin on product or collection pages?](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/check-if-current-customer-user-is-an-admin-on-product-or-collection-pages-222108)

Currently there's no nice way to check for admins like you can for customers. Your options are to [tag your customers as admins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483251/1367622) and only show your template if the customer has the admin tag, or [check against the customer's email address](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/check-if-current-customer-user-is-an-admin-on-product-or-collection-pages-222108) to determine if they are an admin.